# Using map and zip to sum multiple vectors in a matrix

Tags: python, vector, mapreduce, vectorization, word2vec

EDIT: Original post was too long winded...

**Is there any way to vectorize the operation below - maybe using map, numpy or list comprehension?** I do not want to use explicit for loops.

```
vec = np.zeros(150,)
for i in range(len(w)):
    vec += matrix[a.index(list(w)[i])]*w[list(w)[i]]
```

For example, like so:

```
vec = map(sum, [zip(vec, matrix[a.index(list(w)[i])]*w[list(w)[i]]) for i in range(len(w))] )
```

The problem with my `map` code above is that I get `TypeError`'s. If anyone can advise that would be great, thanks.

Comment: Rather than `map` your loop makes me think of being replaceable with a [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Comment: What type is `w`?

Comment: `w` is a dictionary